# htaccess to nginx conversion

Tags: apache, nginx

I'm migrating from apache to nginx. The original htaccess rules are as follow:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Could anyone tell me how can I convert these code into nginx equivalent? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found a few online Apache to Nginx tools:

- http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/
- http://winginx.com/en/htaccess